# Where clause in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql query is as follows

```
IF @StatusId = 10
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
        Risk AS R
        INNER JOIN Statuses AS St ON R.Status_Id=St.Status_Id
        WHERE
        R.MitigationOwner = COALESCE(@MitigationOwner,R.MitigationOwner)
        AND R.RiskFactor = COALESCE(@RiskFactor,R.RiskFactor)
        AND R.RiskArea = COALESCE(@RiskArea,R.RiskArea)
        AND R.AddedWhen BETWEEN 
        COALESCE(CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate+'00:00:00',120),R.AddedWhen) AND 
        COALESCE(CONVERT(DATETIME,@EndDate+'23:59:59',120),R.AddedWhen)
    END
```

When I pass only status Id and all other variables are null, then records with NULL MitigationOwner or ModifiedDate are not displayed..
What is wrong in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that by ModifiedDate you meant R.AddedWhen

try this:

```
SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
        Risk AS R
        INNER JOIN Statuses AS St ON R.Status_Id=St.Status_Id
        WHERE
        (R.MitigationOwner = COALESCE(@MitigationOwner,R.MitigationOwner) OR R.MitigationOwner IS NULL)
        AND R.RiskFactor = COALESCE(@RiskFactor,R.RiskFactor)
        AND R.RiskArea = COALESCE(@RiskArea,R.RiskArea)
        AND (R.AddedWhen BETWEEN 
        COALESCE(CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate+'00:00:00',120),R.AddedWhen) AND 
        COALESCE(CONVERT(DATETIME,@EndDate+'23:59:59',120),R.AddedWhen) OR R.AddedWhen IS NULL)
```

Comment: @user1181942 you're welcome, you should mark answers as accepted when they solve your problem, so that others won't have to go trough all the answers to find the right one :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the form:

```
...
(R.MitigationOwner = @MitigationOwner OR  @MitigationOwner IS NULL)
...
```

This is optimised in SQL Server. COALESCE isn't.

Edit: This does the same as Paul Williams' answer but his answer allows explicit "NULL = NULL" matches. m ylogic is simpler because NULL never equals NULL.

Comment: I believe it's the column (R.MitigationOwner) you should compare to null not the variable. "then records with NULL MitigationOwner or ModifiedDate are not displayed" by @user1181942

Comment: @EuclidesMulémbwè: The problem happens when @MitigationOwner is NULL. Then you have `NULL = COALESCE(NULL, NULL)` which is unknown = false. So when @MitigationOwner is null, you don't compre it against R.MitigationOwner. When NOT NULL, you do.

Answer (score 1):

If R.MitigationOwner can be null, then your comparison clause:

```
WHERE
R.MitigationOwner = COALESCE(@MitigationOwner,R.MitigationOwner)
```

Must be rewritten to handle NULL values:

```
WHERE
((R.MitigationOwner IS NULL AND @MitigationOwner IS NULL)
 OR (R.MitigationOwner = @MitigationOwner))
```

See [this article on Wikipedia about NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null).

Comment: Thanks..I could not follow this link but I searched in Wikipedia...It really added to my knowledge

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed the link to point to the correct article.